# Drupal 9 - 403 error when viewing User Profile anonymously

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I'm building out a new Drupal 9 site and have ran into a weird issue where I can not view any user profile page anonymously. I get a 403 error on the page and the only thing it spits out is "You are not authorized to access this page."

All of this people are active and not blocked. I thought it could be an issue with layout builder but it doesn't make a difference. I haven't had this issue with any content types, just user profiles.

The site is running on a bootstrap theme and is hosted via Pantheon. Here's what spits out the message when viewing a profile page anonymously:

```
<div class="region region-content">
<div data-drupal-messages-fallback="" class="hidden"></div>
            <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
            <!-- THEME HOOK: 'block' -->
            <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
               * block--mainpagecontent.html.twig
               * block--system-main-block.html.twig
               x block--system.html.twig
               * block.html.twig
            -->
            <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/composer/bootstrap/templates/block/block--system.html.twig' -->
              You are not authorized to access this page.
            
            <!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/composer/bootstrap/templates/block/block--system.html.twig' -->
            
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to what would be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For a anonymous user to be able to see user profile pages you need to grant that permission.

Go to

```
/admin/people/permissions
```

Under “User -> View user information” grant the necessary permission.

Now, think twice.
It might be a very bad idea to grant this kind of permission.
Consider all the impacts on security and privacy among others.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple that I was just overlooking.